# Publish an Excel add-in

Tags: excel, add-in, publish, office-js

I developed an add-in in JavaScript.
I don't understand how to easily publish and install the Excel add-in that I developed.
I don't want it to be in the Office Add-ins store, just want to send it to specific people to help them get their work done.
How do I get started and what are the processes to follow? I need the installation and uninstallation process to be as easy & quick as possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/publish/publish) lead me to the section of [Sideload Office Add-ins for testing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/sideload-office-add-ins-for-testing), in which I watched [Michael Zlatkovsky](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XXsAw2UUiQo)
's video.
I could successfully load it for an outside-testing use via Excel Online (4:05).
I created the XML file for my solution via Visual Studio, by following [this tutorial](https://channel9.msdn.com/series/officejs/End-to-End-Walkthrough-of-Excel-JavaScript-Add-in-Development) (the part of the XML creation is in 1 hour 21 minutes and further).

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/publish/publish) is the official documentation how to deploy an Add-In in your organization.

Comment: Thanks, but the thing is, I get [this](http://i.imgur.com/nyrFvQQ.png) error message when I launch office after adding the add-in's root URL (put in a free host that I registered to a while back). What other thing can I do?

Comment: That error usually means that you didn't redeploy the updated manifest to your add-in catalog when you transitioned from development to production. Also, please add some details of the scenario. For example, which of the methods described in the documentation that Alex linked to are you using?

Comment: @RickKirkham Thanks to you, I went back to the documentation page, went to the Sideload method, watched [the video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XXsAw2UUiQo&t=4m8s) and the magic happened in Excel Online. Thanks a lot! If you'll post your answer as a standalone response, I'll mark it as my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Copying this from comment to answer at the OP's request:
That error ["... add-ins inserted during development are only available when debugging ..."]usually means that you didn't redeploy the updated manifest to your add-in catalog when you transitioned from development to production.

Comment: Then how do I transition to production?

Comment: Change the URLs in the manifest that point to localhost so that they point to the domain where you are hosting the production add-in. Then deploy the changed manifest to your catalog.